# Does %{REQUEST_URI} always begin with slash?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've performed tests in 2-3 apache servers and, if my mind doesn't betray me, `%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with an `/`, even if the requested URL is http://domain.com (without and ending slash). However i've seen .htaccess files that have rules like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ http...
```

I mean, would this kind of rule ever match `{REQUEST_URI}`? Or maybe i'm missing something about mod_rewrite (isn't the parameter after `RewriteRule` just the same as `%{REQUEST_URI}` and therefore no match would happen?).

If someone can enlighten me about this, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: [RTFM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars)

Answer (score 7):

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash if placed in DocumentRoot) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

`%{REQUEST_URI}` on the other hand always contains full URI values starting from `/` after domain name.

It will be clear with these examples for this URL:

```
URL: http://domain.com/path/files/user.php
```

**Case 1:** `.htaccess` is placed in `DocumentRoot`:

```
%{REQUEST_URI}: /path/files/user.php
RewriteRule pattern: path/files/user.php
```

**Case 2:** `.htaccess` is placed in `DocumentRoot/path/`:

```
%{REQUEST_URI}: /path/files/user.php
RewriteRule pattern: files/user.php
```

**Case 3:** `.htaccess` is placed in `DocumentRoot/path/files/`:

```
%{REQUEST_URI}: /path/files/user.php
RewriteRule pattern: user.php
```

Answer (score 5):

`RewriteRule` patterns do not necessarily match against `%{REQUEST_URI}`. From [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched):

> #### What is matched?
>
> In [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) context, The Pattern will initially be matched
>   against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before
>   the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the *filesystem* path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current `RewriteRule` (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

Since you saw these in an `htaccess` file, the path to be matched will not start with a `/`, since the prefix removed would contain at least a `/`.