# Https redirection works wrong

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, http-redirect

We are facing a problem with HTTP links on our Wordpress Website, the redirection rule to HTTPS page fails to open the correct link.
I.e: http://erasmusplus.dz/projets-cbhe/  redirect to https://erasmusplus.dzprojets-cbhe/
unstead of:  https://erasmusplus.dz/projets-cbhe/    ("/" is missing)
I have only FTP and Wordpress access:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you in adavnce for your help.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the responses to: [Does %{REQUEST_URI} always begin with slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320882/does-request-uri-always-begin-with-slash)

Essentially the location of the `.htaccess` file will dictate the prefix slash. Try adding a slash explicitly into your redirect link like so:

```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added the slash as you suggested but the problem still remains!

Comment: Have you tried:      `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`